# Delete rows/columns in matrix when values are only 0 across multiple matrices

Tags: r, matrix, filter

I have multiple n*n matrices where each cell either contains values 0 or 1. My goal is to delete all IDs after a certain ID, where rows *and* columns have only 0's in *all* matrices of my data set.

Here is some data:

```
m1 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 4, 4)
m2 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 4, 4)
```

In this example, I would like to check for every ID after 2 if the corresponding row and column shows only 0's for both matrices. Here, this is true for ID 2&3: I then want to delete row & column 3 in all matrices, but keep row & column 2.

As you can imagine, my data set is a lot bigger and this can't be done by hand.

I tried:

```
m1b <- m1 [which(rowSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0 & colSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0), ]
```

But this omits the first 2 rows and only checks one matrix. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have to put the column condition after the comma
2. Your row condition is on `m1[3:4,]` but you apply it on `m1`. `which(rowSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0)` returns 2 but it is the 4th row of `m1`, you need to add 2 to the results of which and tell you want to keep the 2 first rows by concatenate the results with 1 and 2

For one matrix, you can do:

```r
m1[c(1, 2, 2 + which(rowSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0)), which(colSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0)]
```

or

```r
m1[c(rep(TRUE, 2), rowSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0), colSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0]
```

Now, to get the conditions for multiple matrices, you can use `&` between vectors of boolean

```r
columnToKeep <- (colSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0) & (colSums(m2[3:4,]) > 0)
rowToKeep <- (c(rep(TRUE, 2), rowSums(m1[3:4,]) > 0)) & (c(rep(TRUE, 2), rowSums(m2[3:4,]) > 0))
m1[rowToKeep, columnToKeep]
m2[rowToKeep, columnToKeep]
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful already. I did the following:
columnToKeep <- c(TRUE, TRUE, colSums(s2015id[,115:248]) > 0 & colSums(s2016id[,115:248]) > 0)
rowToKeep <- c(TRUE, TRUE, rowSums(s2015id[115:248,]) > 0 & rowSums(s2016id[115:248,]) > 0)

However, when applying this to a matrix like this:
s2015id_b <- s2015id[rowToKeep, columnToKeep]

It still deletes the first 114 ID's (real data here, of course) where the conditions are matched. I'm not sure why.

I shall also read more into R's handling of matrices, since I would have never guessed your first approach.

Comment: Apologies that this looks like such a mess - I was unaware that comments will not allow formatting.

Comment: you need to add a number of TRUE equivalent to the first n rows you want to keep `c(rep(TRUE, 114), rowSums(s2015id[115:248,]) > 0))`

Comment: You can read https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html on how subsetting vectors, matrices...

Comment: Many thanks, Quentin. This worked very well and I will read your link to improve my understanding of subsetting and R grammar in general.